# Global include for all classes ? c++

Tags: c++, class, include, declaration

I have these two classes:

include/state.hpp :

```
#include "connection.hpp"
#include <vector>

class state {
    private:
        vector<connection*> conns;
        ...
};
```

include/connection.hpp :

```
#include "state.hpp"

class connection {
    private:
        state *next;
        ...
};
```

And my src/main.cpp :

```
#include "../include/state.hpp"
#include "../include/connection.hpp"

int main(...) {
    ...
}
```

The problem is that when I compile I get a lot of errors because the compiler doesnt know what is "state" or "connection" when it needs them. I found a solution doing this:

include/state.hpp :

```
#include "connection.hpp"
#include <vector>

class connection;

class state {
    private:
        vector<connection*> conns;
        ...
};
```

include/connection.hpp :

```
#include "state.hpp"

class state;

class connection {
    private:
        state *next;
        ...
};
```

Anyway, this is all but clean in my opinion. Should I create other .hpp file with all the classes and include them in the rest of the .hpp like this ? :

```
include/classes.hpp :

class state;
class connection;
class foo;
...
```

Is there a better solution ?

Comment: it looks like design flaw, connection has state, state is basically enum - it does NOT have connections (like in your example), if you want to get all connections by state - create separate class, like connection manager, which will handle map<state/connections>

Comment: Forward-declaring your classes is the normal solution for this. `classes.hpp` is not.